# Preventing FOUC when loading stylesheet from local storage

Tags: javascript, css, cookies, local-storage

I'm making a website that has the option to load a "night mode" css stylesheet that they can toggle on and off. I'd like the style to persist as long as they're using the website. (It's a WordPress site.)

My lame attempt at the moment is to fill in the stylesheet with an IIFE. Obviously it's bad, and also I still get flash of unstyled content.

```
<link href="" id="night-css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
(function () {
    var style = localStorage.getItem('stylesheet');
    if (style) {
        document.getElementById('night-css').setAttribute('href', style);
    }
})()
</script>
```

Would anyone have a suggestion for how to do this client-side?

Comment: don't save the stylesheet in the `localStorage` save just a boolean if true turn to dark mode else nothing

Comment: If that script tag is in head before other scripts and right after the link tag I don't see why FOUC would occur